# Is there any form of sandboxing available to build and test functionality against?

Tags: twilio

I'm an indie developer and love the platform but have recently discovered that you [can't buy phone numbers from a trial account](http://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21404). I've also seen that "sandboxing" is a deprecated feature and was hoping that something similar has been created in it's place. For someone like me money is tight and I'd like to get a basic app together before having to pay for the platform.

Is there anyway that I can test these platform features without incurring a cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio employee here.

For development, we don't charge you until you upgrade. That said, to get you started, you get one free phone number when you sign up. It is 100% yours to do with as you wish.. with a couple limitations: You can only send SMS or place calls to phone numbers you've verified with us.

Also, once you've upgraded you can still do testing and development for free with our Test Credentials. The full details are on the site - http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials - but this is probably the most important bit for you:

> You use these credentials in the same way as your live credentials.
>   However, when you authenticate with your test credentials, we will not
>   charge your account, update the state of your account, or connect to
>   real phone numbers. You can now pretend to buy a phone number, or send
>   an SMS, without actually doing so.